# Mask RCNN uses CPU instead of GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm using the Mask RCNN library which is based on tenserflow and I can't seem to get it to run on my GPU (1080TI). The inference time is 4-5 seconds, during which I see a usage spike on my cpu but not my gpu. Any possible fixes for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is either because that GPU_COUNT is set to 0 in `config.py` or you don't have `tensorflow-gpu` installed (which is required for tensorflow to run on GPU)

Comment: I've already checked that GPU_COUNT is set to 1 and I had installed tensorflow-gpu but maybe it's not picking it up?

Comment: Had to install newer version of tensorflow-gpu